# Which folder is geth storing data? (Ubuntu)

Tags: go-ethereum, storage

I just installed go-ethereum (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum), and I am running a node. I am using Ubuntu.
I want to ask in which folder is the block data being stored? Where I can see how many blocks it has downloaded?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

the default for Linux is `$HOME/.ethereum`

```
user@host :~/.ethereum$ cd $HOME/.ethereum
user@host :~/.ethereum$ ls
blocks  database  details  geth  geth.ipc  history  keystore  network.rlp  protocol  state
user@host :~/.ethereum$
```

you can change this with `--datadir` parameter

when you sync the blocks are downloaded in about a few hours, but what takes a lot to download is the state, blocks take about 60GB, but the state takes 700GB

blocks are stored mostly in `geth/chaindata/` directory, but when they pass about 100k blocks they are moved to `geth/chaindata/ancient` directory

you can check sync status with

```
> eth.syncing
```

on the console. Currently the amount of state entries is approaching to 1 billion.

Answer (score 0):

I opened chaindata folder, there are lots of files like:

```
000197.ldb  044223.ldb  058455.ldb  072099.ldb  074159.ldb  078064.ldb
000198.ldb  044234.ldb  058457.ldb  072101.ldb  074161.ldb  078065.ldb
000199.ldb  044245.ldb  058463.ldb  072102.ldb  074162.ldb  078066.ldb
000200.ldb  044253.ldb  058465.ldb  072103.ldb  074163.ldb  078067.ldb
000201.ldb  044264.ldb  058467.ldb  072104.ldb  074164.ldb  078068.ldb
000202.ldb  044291.ldb  058469.ldb  072105.ldb  074165.ldb  078069.ldb
```

Do those numbers  for example 000197 represent block number?

Comment: Geth stores recent blocks in a LevelDB database. Those are fixed-size chunks of the same database. Those numbers do not represent the block number though.